Sound output keeps swapping
The sound output of my MacBook Pro M1 keeps swapping. It's very annoying.
The problem started after I bought a UGREEN usb-c to RCA cable. The sound keeps swapping from the USB-C cable to internal output every 15min roughly. I don't have this problem with my Android phone and a Dell laptop which runs with Ubuntu so I think the problem comes from my MacBook.
I don't know if it can help but I dumped system logs when the problem occurs :
IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending message type 0xe0000130 from service USB2@...

I [ik] parseDTIMEcounter@30675: DTIM missed count: p2p(0), iovar(0), scan(0), roam(0), homechan(0), sleep(0), misc(0)LQM-WIFI: (HighBand)  rxNotPrimary20s=0 ucodeLateDrop=0 rxInvalidUcodeLateWrongMACPHY=0 rxLate30us=0 rxLegacyFrmInvalid=0 txSifsErr=0 ooseqMacSusp=0
usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::terminateDevice: destroying 0x3302/17c2/0100 (USB-C Audio): hardware connection lost
IOPortTransportStateUSB2::setDataRate(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] dateRate: 0 [None]
IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: NO, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 0)
IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending message type 0xe0000130 from service USB2@...

AppleUSBIORequest: AppleUSBIORequest::complete: device 1 (USB-C Audio@01100000) endpoint 0x83: status 0xe00002ed (transaction error): 0 bytes transferred
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:1008][0x100001929] CompleteInReport:0xe00002ed
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:795][0x100001929] Schedule retry reason:0xe00002ed count:9 deadline:50ms
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::willTerminate(<ptr>, 1)
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setState(0x0. oldState=0x1)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::willTerminate(<ptr>, 1) returns 1
DK: AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice-0x100001929:force close (IOUSBHostInterface-0x100001922)
DK: AppleUserHIDEventDriver-0x10000192f:force close (IOHIDInterface-0x10000192e)
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001929 close by AppleUserHIDEventDriver:0x10000192f (0x0)
DK: AppleUserHIDEventDriver-0x10000192f:force close (AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice-0x100001929)
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001929 message: 0xe0000010 from: 0x100001922 1

AppleUserHIDEventDriver:0x10000192f stop

+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::removeClient(<ptr>)
+-IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::safeLogError kErrorLogDumpCounters mStreamErrorCountsUpdated=0
- IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::removeClient(<ptr>)
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::decrementActiveUserClients() - 0 returns 0x0
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::setOnline(0)
+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::removeClient(<ptr>)
+-IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::safeLogError kErrorLogDumpCounters mStreamErrorCountsUpdated=0
- IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::removeClient(<ptr>)
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:466][0x100001929] Close interface: 0x100001922 0x0
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
[AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:137][0x100001929] Stop: 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::detachUserClients
  will invoke userClients->flushCollection ()
  completed userClients->flushCollection ()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::detachUserClients returns 0x0
+- IOAudioEngine::detachUserClientsAction(<ptr>, 0, 0, 0, 0) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopAudioEngine()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopAudioEngine() returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::detachAudioStreams()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::detachAudioStreams()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
  completed removeEventSource ( ... )
  completed release ()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
[AppleUserHIDEventDriver.cpp:326][0x10000192f] Stop: 0x0
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001929 stop

AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001929 handleStop src: 0 srfc: 0 srtc: 0 srt: 0 grc: 0 grfc: 0 grtc: 0 grt: 0 irc: 0 irt: 0

+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::removeAllTimerEvents()
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::removeAllTimerEvents()
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::deactivateAllAudioEngines()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopAudioEngine()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopAudioEngine() returns 0x0
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::deactivateAllAudioEngines()
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
[IOUserHIDEventService.cpp:360][0x10000192f] Close interface: 0x10000192e 0x0
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Client <ptr> is requesting 150mA wake and 0mA sleep for port 2
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Client <ptr> port 2 has EDT current overrides of 3000mA wake and 3000mA sleep
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Granting 150mA wake and 0mA sleep based on override for port 2
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::free()
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::deactivateAllAudioEngines()
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::deactivateAllAudioEngines()
  did deactiveateAllAudioEngines ()
  did detachAllAudioPorts ()
  did timerEvents->release ()
  did workLoop->removeEventSource ( timerEventSource )
  did workLoop->removeEventSource ( reserved->idleTimer )
  did IOFree ()
  did workLoop->removeEventSource ( commandGate )
  did workLoop->release ()
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::free()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::free()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::free()
+ Speaker::startIOEngineGated()+ Speaker startTransport
Speaker: streaming audio
- Speaker startTransport ret=success(0)- Speaker::startIOEngineGated() ret=success(0)IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending message type 0xe0000130 from service USB2@...

IOPortTransportStateUSB2::setDataRate(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] dateRate: 2 [12 Mbps (Full Speed)]
IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending message type 0xe0000130 from service USB2@...

usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::enumerateDeviceComplete_block_invoke: enumerated 0x3302/17c2/0100 (USB-C Audio / 1) at 12 Mbps
IOPortTransportState::setMetadata(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting metadata... (metadata: YES, metadata.count: 8)
IOPortTransportState::handleMetadataChanges(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Handling metadata changes... (shouldReregisterService: NO)
IOPortTransportState::_updatePreDefinedMetadataProperties(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Updating pre-defined metadata properties...
IOPortTransportState::_updatePreDefinedMetadataProperties(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Updated 0 pre-defined metadata properties!
IOPortTransportState::setHash(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] hash: YES
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Client <ptr> is requesting 150mA wake and 0mA sleep for port 2
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Client <ptr> port 2 has EDT current overrides of 3000mA wake and 3000mA sleep
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Granting 150mA wake and 0mA sleep based on override for port 2
USB-C Audio@01100000: IOUSBHostDevice::setConfigurationGated: AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice selected configuration 1
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::init(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::init(<ptr>) returns 1
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::start(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setDeviceModelName(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setDeviceModelName(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setDeviceName(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setDeviceName(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setManufacturerName(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setManufacturerName(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::init(0)
  properties(0) == NULL
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setState(0x0. oldState=0)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::init(0)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::activateAudioEngine(<ptr>, 1)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::start(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::start(<ptr>, <ptr>)
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::initHardware(<ptr>)
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setSampleRate(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setNumSampleFramesPerBuffer(0x8000)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setNumSampleFramesPerBuffer(0x8000)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::start(<ptr>)
Driver com.apple.AppleUserHIDDrivers has crashed 0 time(s)
DK: AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice-0x100001af1 using existing server IOUserServer(com.apple.driverkit.AppleUserHIDDrivers-0x100000bc7)-0x100000be2
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 start (state:0x0)

[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:1156][0x100001af1] bulk pipe support:0 (reason: vendorID (13058))
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:552][0x100001af1] Open interface: 0x100001aec
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:1222][0x100001af1] found in pipe (addr:131, type:3)
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:709][0x100001af1] HID descriptor interface:2 index:0 length:33 33 33
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 start (state:0x4)

AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 start

[ElementContainer] Element value capacity 264

[ElementContainer] Report count: 1

[ElementContainer] Report ID: 0 input:8 output:0 feature:0

[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:340][0x100001af1] inPipe:1  inputReportSize:1 inMaxPacketSize:16 inBufferSize:16
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:383][0x100001af1] outPipe:0  outMaxPacketSize:0
[AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:126][0x100001af1] Start ret: 0x0
DK: AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice-0x100001af1::start(IOUSBHostInterface-0x100001aec) ok
+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::validateFormat(<ptr>, 0, <ptr>)
  2: streamFormat->fNumChannels = 2
  0x6c70636d: streamFormat->fSampleFormat = 0x6c70636d
  0x73696e74: streamFormat->fNumericRepresentation = 0x73696e74
  16: streamFormat->fBitDepth = 16
  16: streamFormat->fBitWidth = 16
  0: streamFormat->fAlignment = 0
  1: streamFormat->fByteOrder = 1
- IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::validateFormat(<ptr>, 0, <ptr>) returns 1
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::beginConfigurationChange()
+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::setFormat(<ptr>, <ptr>)
+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::validateFormat(<ptr>, <ptr>, <ptr>)
  2: streamFormat->fNumChannels = 2
  0x6c70636d: streamFormat->fSampleFormat = 0x6c70636d
  0x73696e74: streamFormat->fNumericRepresentation = 0x73696e74
  16: streamFormat->fBitDepth = 16
  16: streamFormat->fBitWidth = 16
  0: streamFormat->fAlignment = 0
  1: streamFormat->fByteOrder = 1
- IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::validateFormat(<ptr>, <ptr>, <ptr>) returns 1
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::pauseAudioEngine()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::pauseAudioEngine() returns 0x0
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::performFormatChange(<ptr>, <ptr>, <ptr>, 0)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::pauseAudioEngine()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::pauseAudioEngine() returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setNumSampleFramesPerBuffer(0x0)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setNumSampleFramesPerBuffer(0x0)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setNumSampleFramesPerBuffer(0x8000)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setNumSampleFramesPerBuffer(0x8000)
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 creating interfaces

IOHIDInterface:0x100001af7 start for AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1

AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 Matching has vendor DeviceUsagePage : ff0c bundleIdentifier com.apple.AppleUserHIDDrivers ioclass AppleUserHIDEventService but transport and vendorID is missing

+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setOutputSampleOffset(0x49)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setOutputSampleOffset(0x49)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
Driver com.apple.AppleUserHIDDrivers has crashed 0 time(s)
DK: AppleUserHIDEventDriver-0x100001af8 using existing server IOUserServer(com.apple.driverkit.AppleUserHIDDrivers-0x100000bc7)-0x100000be2
AppleUserHIDEventDriver:0x100001af8 start (state:0x0)

[AppleUserHIDEventDriver.cpp:250][0x100001af8] Target macOS
AppleUserHIDEventDriver:0x100001af8 start (state:0x4)

AppleUserHIDEventDriver:0x100001af8 start

AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 open by AppleUserHIDEventDriver:0x100001af8 (0x0)
[IOUserHIDEventService.cpp:161][0x100001af8] Open interface: 0x100001af7
[AppleUserHIDEventDriver.cpp:211][0x100001af8] parseElements: led: 0
[AppleUserHIDEventService.cpp:988][0x100001af8] parseElements: vendor (primary): 0 vendor (child): 0 multiaxis: 0 keyboard: 0 unicode: 0 0 biometric: 0 accel 0 gyro: 0 compass: 0 temperature: 0 orientation 0 0 sensorPropsCaps 0
[IOUserHIDEventDriver.cpp:942][0x100001af8] parseElements: keyboard: 8 pointer: 0 0 scroll: 0 led: 0 digitizer: 0 proximity: 0 gameController: 0
[AppleUserHIDEventService.cpp:247][0x100001af8] Start ret: 0x0
[AppleUserHIDEventDriver.cpp:315][0x100001af8] Start ret: 0x0
[AppleUserHIDEventDriver.cpp:116][0x100001af8] USB-C Audio usagePage: 12 usage: 1 vid: 13058 pid: 6082
DK: AppleUserHIDEventDriver-0x100001af8::start(IOHIDInterface-0x100001af7) ok
23 duplicate reports for Sandbox: Family(11483) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.contactsd.persistenceSandbox: icdd(514) allow file-read-data /Library/Image Capture/Devices+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::resumeAudioEngine()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::resumeAudioEngine() returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::updateChannelNumbers ()
  o=0 i=0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::updateChannelNumbers ()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::sendFormatChangeNotification(<ptr>)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::sendFormatChangeNotification(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::resumeAudioEngine()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::resumeAudioEngine() returns 0x0
IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::setFormat(<ptr>, <ptr>) returns 0x0Speaker: Zero time stamp captured ( 15840, 237770701251)
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::completeConfigurationChange()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::addAudioStream(<ptr>)
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setRunEraseHead(1)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::addAudioStream(<ptr>) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::start(<ptr>, <ptr>)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::start(<ptr>) returns 1
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::registerService(0x8)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::updateChannelNumbers ()
  o=2 i=0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::updateChannelNumbers ()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::registerService(0x8)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::activateAudioEngine(<ptr>, 1) returns 0x0
+-IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::initHardware(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::newUserClient(0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0, <ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::initWithAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0)
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::setOnline(0)
  ConnectionID:0x7eee8561
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::initWithAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0) returns 1
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient::withAudioEngine(<ptr>, 0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0) returns <ptr>
+ IOAudioEngine::addUserClientAction(<ptr>, <ptr>)
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::addUserClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngine::addUserClientAction(<ptr>, <ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::newUserClient(0x<ptr>, <ptr>, 0x0, 0, <ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::clientMemoryForType(0x0, 0x0, <ptr>)
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::getStatusDescriptor()
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::clientMemoryForType(0x0, 0x1000, <ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::registerFormatNotification(0x<ptr>, 0x44e) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerNotificationAction(<ptr>, <ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::registerNotificationPort(0x<ptr>, 0x0, 0x44e) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod, selector=0x0,   arg0 0x0, arg1 0x102cb8000, arg2 0x8010 arg3 0x455 
  scalarInputCount=0x4  structureInputSize 0x0, scalarOutputCount 0x0, structureOutputSize 0x0 
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerBuffer64 0x0 0x102cb8000 0x8010 0x455
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient::safeRegisterClientBuffer64 <ptr> 
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::registerClientBuffer64  (<ptr>[1], 0x102cb8000, 0x8010, 0x455)
  null clientBufferSetList
  did not find clientBufferSetList for ID 0x455 
  clientBuffer->mAudioClientBuffer32.sourceBuffer before offset: <ptr>, offset size: 16
  clientBuffer->mAudioClientBuffer32.sourceBuffer after offset: <ptr>
  null clientBufferSetList
  did not find clientBufferSetList for ID 0x455 
  creating new IOAudioClientBufferSet 
  output 
  !isOnline 
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerClientBuffer64() result 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::safeRegisterClientBuffer64  returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::registerBuffer64 0x0 0x102cb8000 0x8010 0x455 returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod, selector=0x3,   arg0 0x0, arg1 0x0, arg2 0x0 arg3 0x0 
  scalarInputCount=0x0  structureInputSize 0x0, scalarOutputCount 0x0, structureOutputSize 0x0 
+ IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::startClient() - 0
  audioEngine && !isInactive(). State = 0 
  audioEngine->getState() != kIOAudioEnginePaused 
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::setOnline(1)
  !isOnline() setting online 
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::startClient(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::incrementActiveUserClients() - 0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::startAudioEngine(state = 0)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::audioEngineStarting() - numRunningAudioEngines = 0
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::initiatePowerStateChange(0) - current = 1 - pending = 2
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::protectedCompletePowerStateChange() - current = 1 - pending = 2
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::protectedCompletePowerStateChange() - current = 2 - pending = 2 returns 0x0
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::initiatePowerStateChange(0) - current = 2 - pending = 2 returns 0x0
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::audioEngineStarting() - numRunningAudioEngines = 1
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopEngineAtPosition(0,0)
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::resetStatusBuffer()
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setState(0x1. oldState=0)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::getTimerInterval()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::startAudioEngine() returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::incrementActiveUserClients() - 1 returns 0
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::startClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
  engine started 
  bufferSet <ptr> 
  output clientBuffer <ptr> 
+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::addClient(<ptr>)
- IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::addClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::startClient() - 1 returns 0x0
- IOAudioEngineUserClient::externalMethod returns 0x0
+ Speaker::stopIOEngineGated()+ Speaker stopTransportSpeaker: off
- Speaker stopTransport ret=success(0)- Speaker::stopIOEngineGated() ret=success(0)handleReport - ignoring redundant message.
1 duplicate report for Sandbox: icdd(514) allow file-read-data /Library/Image Capture/DevicesSandbox: Family(11483) deny(1) mach-lookup com.apple.contactsd.persistencehandleReport - ignoring redundant message.
handleReport - ignoring redundant message.
IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending message type 0xe0000130 from service USB2@...

usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::terminateDevice: destroying 0x3302/17c2/0100 (USB-C Audio): hardware connection lost
IOPortTransportStateUSB2::setDataRate(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] dateRate: 0 [None]
IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: NO, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 0)
IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending message type 0xe0000130 from service USB2@...

AppleUSBIORequest: AppleUSBIORequest::complete: device 1 (USB-C Audio@01100000) endpoint 0x83: status 0xe00002ed (transaction error): 0 bytes transferred
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:1008][0x100001af1] CompleteInReport:0xe00002ed
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:795][0x100001af1] Schedule retry reason:0xe00002ed count:9 deadline:50ms
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::willTerminate(<ptr>, 1)
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setState(0x0. oldState=0x1)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::willTerminate(<ptr>, 1) returns 1
DK: AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice-0x100001af1:force close (IOUSBHostInterface-0x100001aec)
DK: AppleUserHIDEventDriver-0x100001af8:force close (IOHIDInterface-0x100001af7)
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 close by AppleUserHIDEventDriver:0x100001af8 (0x0)
DK: AppleUserHIDEventDriver-0x100001af8:force close (AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice-0x100001af1)
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 message: 0xe0000010 from: 0x100001aec 1

AppleUserHIDEventDriver:0x100001af8 stop

+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::removeClient(<ptr>)
+-IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::safeLogError kErrorLogDumpCounters mStreamErrorCountsUpdated=0
- IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::removeClient(<ptr>)
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::decrementActiveUserClients() - 0 returns 0x0
+- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopClient(<ptr>) returns 0x0
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::setOnline(0)
+ IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::removeClient(<ptr>)
+-IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::safeLogError kErrorLogDumpCounters mStreamErrorCountsUpdated=0
- IOAudioStream[<ptr>]::removeClient(<ptr>)
+- IOAudioEngineUserClient[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::detachUserClients
  will invoke userClients->flushCollection ()
  completed userClients->flushCollection ()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::detachUserClients returns 0x0
+- IOAudioEngine::detachUserClientsAction(<ptr>, 0, 0, 0, 0) returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopAudioEngine()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopAudioEngine() returns 0x0
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::detachAudioStreams()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::detachAudioStreams()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
  completed removeEventSource ( ... )
  completed release ()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 stop

AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001af1 handleStop src: 0 srfc: 0 srtc: 0 srt: 0 grc: 0 grfc: 0 grtc: 0 grt: 0 irc: 0 irt: 0

+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::removeAllTimerEvents()
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::removeAllTimerEvents()
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::deactivateAllAudioEngines()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopAudioEngine()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::stopAudioEngine() returns 0x0
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::deactivateAllAudioEngines()
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::stop(<ptr>)
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Client <ptr> is requesting 150mA wake and 0mA sleep for port 2
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Client <ptr> port 2 has EDT current overrides of 3000mA wake and 3000mA sleep
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Granting 150mA wake and 0mA sleep based on override for port 2
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:466][0x100001af1] Close interface: 0x100001aec 0x0
[AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:137][0x100001af1] Stop: 0x0
[AppleUserHIDEventDriver.cpp:326][0x100001af8] Stop: 0x0
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::free()
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::deactivateAllAudioEngines()
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::deactivateAllAudioEngines()
  did deactiveateAllAudioEngines ()
  did detachAllAudioPorts ()
  did timerEvents->release ()
  did workLoop->removeEventSource ( timerEventSource )
  did workLoop->removeEventSource ( reserved->idleTimer )
[IOUserHIDEventService.cpp:360][0x100001af8] Close interface: 0x100001af7 0x0
  did IOFree ()
  did workLoop->removeEventSource ( commandGate )
  did workLoop->release ()
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::free()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::free()
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::removeAllDefaultAudioControls()
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::free()
+ Speaker::startIOEngineGated()+ Speaker startTransport
Speaker: streaming audio
- Speaker startTransport ret=success(0)- Speaker::startIOEngineGated() ret=success(0)IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending message type 0xe0000130 from service USB2@...

IOPortTransportStateUSB2::setDataRate(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] dateRate: 2 [12 Mbps (Full Speed)]
IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending message type 0xe0000130 from service USB2@...

usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::enumerateDeviceComplete_block_invoke: enumerated 0x3302/17c2/0100 (USB-C Audio / 1) at 12 Mbps
IOPortTransportState::setMetadata(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting metadata... (metadata: YES, metadata.count: 8)
IOPortTransportState::handleMetadataChanges(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Handling metadata changes... (shouldReregisterService: NO)
IOPortTransportState::_updatePreDefinedMetadataProperties(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Updating pre-defined metadata properties...
IOPortTransportState::_updatePreDefinedMetadataProperties(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Updated 0 pre-defined metadata properties!
IOPortTransportState::setHash(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] hash: YES
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Client <ptr> is requesting 150mA wake and 0mA sleep for port 2
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Client <ptr> port 2 has EDT current overrides of 3000mA wake and 3000mA sleep
AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC@: AppleUSBHostResourcesTypeC::allocateDownstreamBusCurrentGated: Granting 150mA wake and 0mA sleep based on override for port 2
USB-C Audio@01100000: IOUSBHostDevice::setConfigurationGated: AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice selected configuration 1
Driver com.apple.AppleUserHIDDrivers has crashed 0 time(s)
DK: AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice-0x100001b11 using existing server IOUserServer(com.apple.driverkit.AppleUserHIDDrivers-0x100000bc7)-0x100000be2
AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice:0x100001b11 start (state:0x0)

+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::init(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::init(<ptr>) returns 1
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::start(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::start(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setDeviceModelName(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setDeviceModelName(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setDeviceName(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setDeviceName(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setManufacturerName(<ptr>)
- IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::setManufacturerName(<ptr>)
+ IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::init(0)
  properties(0) == NULL
+-IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::setState(0x0. oldState=0)
- IOAudioEngine[<ptr>]::init(0)
+ IOAudioDevice[<ptr>]::activateAudioEngine(<ptr>, 1)
[IOUserUSBHostHIDDevice.cpp:1156][0x100001b11] bulk pipe support:0 (reason: vendorID (13058))

I guess the problem occurred twice when these 2 logs were dumped :
[7433.465164]: usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::terminateDevice: destroying 0x3302/17c2/0100 (USB-C Audio): hardware connection lost

[7437.654124]: usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::terminateDevice: destroying 0x3302/17c2/0100 (USB-C Audio): hardware connection lost

Any idea to solve this problem ?
Thx

Could you elaborate on the android phone relates to the Mac for your problem? Why would they be related or even relevant? Also - why are you using a new cable that correlates with this problem arriving?

The Android phone demonstrates my new USB-C wire works properly. I use the brand new USB-C wire because before I used an old M-Audio interface at the USB-C wire current place and this M-Audio interface put white noise on my speakers so I had to find a way to replace it.

I would ask Ugreen about it. I've found their products to be pretty good, but I suspect that it's going to sleep after 15 mins, or something like that.

Hmm - there may be some value in android software and some other hardware vendor handling the cable correctly to rule out a totally broken cable, but Mac can push cables harder when the cable signals a certain capability and then can’t meet it from USB standpoint, so I wouldn’t assume it’s compatible just on that data point. Definitely ask the vendor for support, here. If you need it to work with a Mac (and specifically your Mac), that should be the only point you ask them.

I have a UGREEN USB switch and it also intermittently disconnects from my Mac M1. It works flawlessly with a Linux PC. I also see status 0xe00002ed (transaction error) in dmesg. I have replaced the cables, the official Apple USB - USB-c adapter, I've tried powering up the switch with a dedicated 5V power supply as indicated by UGREEN, I tried different ports on both the switch and the Mac, nothing works... And the switch works flawlessly for years on Linux PC. Evidence points to a compatibility issue between UGREEN devices and Mac devices (at least the M1) or OSX, probably to Apple's fault
